# ¿Cómo elimino el fondo blanco de un texto sobre una imagen?

Tags: html, css, web, text, hover

Resulta que tengo una imagen con un `hover` donde un texto se desplaza y se muestra. El problema es que el texto está encerrado en un rectángulo y encima tiene transparencia. Necesitaría quitar esas dos cositas.

¿Puede alguien ayudarme? Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #E8ECF4;
}

#header {
  width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  background-color: #66c2ff;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  /*Le establecemos un ancho*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*Centramos automaticamente*/
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #66c2ff;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: #66c2ff;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #33adff;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.nav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul li ul {
  right: -140px;
  top: 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#Principal {
  /*background-color:rgba(176,196,222,0.6); rgbA */
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  /*opacity: 0.6;*/
  /*filter: alpha(opacity=50); For IE8 and earlier */
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.Flag {
  width: 128px;
  height: 75px;
}

.Flag:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}


/* CONTENEDOR TEXTO EN BANDERA */

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 128px;
  height: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.img-container:before {
  content: '';
  width: 128px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
}

.img-container:hover:before {
  opacity: .50;
}

.img-container p {
  /*width: inherit;  */
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: 100%;
  transition: top .2s linear;
}

.img-container:hover p {
  top: 50%;
}

.NombreContinente {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Logo {
  width: 134px;
  height: 93px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Wondolor's Adventures!</title>
  <link href="Css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="Logo" alt="Home">
    <div id="header">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="Index.html">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="Destinos.html">Destinos</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Europa</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Italia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Francia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Vaticano</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">España</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Inglaterra</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">América</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Argentina</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Brasil</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Ecuador</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">África</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Asia</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Oceanía</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Series</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Viaje a Misiones (2016)</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Viaje a Brasil (2016)</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Misiones en Invierno (2016)</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Viaje por Europa (2017)</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Viaje a Ecuador (2018)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="Principal">
    <p class="NombreContinente">Europa</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="img-container"><img src=http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/es.png class="Flag">
      <p>España</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container"><img src=http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/fr.png class="Flag">
      <p>Francia</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container"><img src=http://www.cenacat.org/app/webroot/files/bandera_vaticano.png class="Flag">
      <p>El Vaticano</p>
    </div>

    <p class="NombreContinente">América</p>
    <hr>
    <img src=Images/Flags/Uruguay.jpg class="Flag">
  </div>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero que te sirva de ayuda las modificaciones que le hice a tu código, solo corrobora de qué manera son aplicadas las opacidades para que no tengas problemas futuros, y corrobora como aplicas los estilos a los diferentes elementos, saludos y excelente día.

```css
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
 a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
 del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
 small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
 b, u, i, center,
 dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
 fieldset, form, label, legend,
 table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
 article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
 figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
 menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
 time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 }
 /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
 footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
 }
   * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#E8ECF4;
   }
   
   
   #header 
   {
    width:80%;
    position:fixed;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   }
   
   
   #header
   {
    background-color:#66c2ff;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    z-index: 100;
   }
   
   .nav {
    width: 100%; /*Le establecemos un ancho*/
    margin:0 auto; /*Centramos automaticamente*/
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   }
   
   ul {
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#66c2ff;
   }
   
   .nav > li {
    float:left;
   }
   
   .nav li a {
    background-color:#66c2ff;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#33adff;
   }
   
   .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
   }
   
   .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
   
   nav
   {
    width:100%;
   }
   
   #Principal
   {
    /*background-color:rgba(176,196,222,0.6); rgbA */
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
    /*filter: alpha(opacity=50); For IE8 and earlier */
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
   }
   
   .Flag
   {
    width: 128px;
    height: 75px;
   }
   .Flag:hover 
   {
    //background: transparent;
   }
   
   
   /* CONTENEDOR TEXTO EN BANDERA */
   .img-container 
   {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   cursor: pointer;
   width: 128px;
   height: 75px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
     }

   .img-container:before 
   {
     content: '';
     width: 128px;
     height: 75px;
     position: absolute;
     background: #fff;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity .2s linear;   
   }

   .img-container:hover:before 
   { 
     //opacity: .50;
   }

   .img-container p 
   {
     /*width: inherit;  */
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     top: 100%; 
     transition: top .2s linear;
              background: transparent;
   }

   .img-container:hover p 
   {    
     top: 50%;
   }
    
   .NombreContinente
   {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
   }
   
   hr
   {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   
   
 .Logo{
 width:134px;
 height:93px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 }
    

**HTML:**
```

```html
<html>
 <head>

  <title>Wondolor's Adventures!</title>
  <link href="Css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
  
 </head>
 <body>
 <header>
  <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="Logo" alt="Home">
  <div id="header">
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav">   
    <li><a href="Index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Destinos.html">Destinos</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Europa</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="">Italia</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Francia</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vaticano</a></li>
        <li><a href="">España</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Inglaterra</a></li>
       </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="">América</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="">Argentina</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Brasil</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ecuador</a></li>
       </ul>
          </li>
      <li><a href="">África</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Asia</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Oceanía</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Series</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="">Viaje a Misiones (2016)</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Viaje a Brasil (2016)</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Misiones en Invierno (2016)</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Viaje por Europa (2017)</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Viaje a Ecuador (2018)</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 
 <div id="Principal">
  <p class="NombreContinente">Europa</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="img-container"><img src=http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/es.png class="Flag"><p>España</p></div>
  <div class="img-container"><img src=http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/fr.png class="Flag"><p>Francia</p></div>
  <div class="img-container"><img src=http://www.cenacat.org/app/webroot/files/bandera_vaticano.png class="Flag"><p>El Vaticano</p></div>
  
  <p class="NombreContinente">América</p>
  <hr>
  <img src=Images/Flags/Uruguay.jpg class="Flag">
 </div>
 
 <div id="fb-root"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha servido.

Comment: @Wondolor si la respuesta te ha sido útil, por favor, márcala como aceptada